# JAR file executes properly on one computer, but doesn't on another. How to fix it?

Tags: java, jar, cmd

A jar file that runs OK on one Windows XP computer (the one it was created on) gives the following error when I execute it on another (Windows 7 Starter):

```
    C:\Users\Pacu\Dropbox\PROZE>java -jar Sokoban.jar
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at Sokoban.RunnableMyFrame.<init>(RunnableMyFrame.java:95)
            at Sokoban.RunnableMyFrame.main(RunnableMyFrame.java:626)
```

Needless to say, nothing happens if I double click the file, which is not the case on the other Windows XP computer.

Both computers have the Java SE Edition Version 7 Update 21 (build 1.7.0 _21-b11).

Comment: Whats on line 95 of RunnableMyFrame? Youre probably attempting to load a resource that is on one machine but not the other

Answer (score 2):

Youre probably attempting to load a resource that is on one machine but not the other.

Solution: Include the resource in the JAR file itself and load using

```
getClass().getResource("/folder/resource")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you debug the problem in the normal manner.  The fact there is a bug which doesn't show on another computer doesn't matter.  You can

- add logging to see what the program is doing
- use the debugger to help debug the code.
- read the code which triggered the exception to determine how the value could be `null`